# Match haproxy path using path_reg

Tags: regex, haproxy

I'm trying to match urls like: /rivers/1, /rivers/2adsfs, /rivers/sdfd2d with:

```
  acl rivers_show   path_reg ^/rivers/\w+/?
```

But that does seem to work. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 8):

HAproxy's regex does not include \w as a character class.  Keep in mind regex is one of the worst performing ACL matches.  You may want to look into use something like this instead, although its its not exactly the same.

acl path_beg /rivers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below the regex to match the give

```
acl rivers_show   path_reg -i ^\/rivers\/[^\.]*
```