# Match regex/wildcard against http header NAMES in haproxy

Tags: regex, http-headers, haproxy

I'd like to add an acl rule to capture the existence of a header **name** that matches the following regex: `^X-\w+-Signature` (or whatever wildcard). Examples to match:

```
X-Abc-Signature
X-Whatever-Signature
X-Service-Signature
```

I know I could explicitly create rules like:

```
acl has_abc_token req.fhdr(X-Abc-Signature) -m found
acl has_whatever_token req.fhdr(X-Whatever-Signature) -m found
acl has_service_token req.fhdr(X-Service-Signature) -m found
```

Is it even possible to do this in haproxy?

Also, it's my understanding is that the `\w` character class [does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12768110/399538) in haproxy?

It looks like `req.hdr_names()` *might* be what I'm looking for, but I'm at a loss at how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out:

```
acl has_sig req.hdr_names() -m reg -i ,X-[A-Za-z]+-Signature
```